# How to fix "Check your microphone" in Chrome for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

Since I am trying to fix this already for 4 hours checking the simplest options and obvious settings: allowing the microphone, testing with external application and last testing with different site (all worked perfectly). I did my research on Google and I found out [this article](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/chrome-refuses-to-use-my-mic-for-google-online-voice-recognition-asoundrc-issue-4175549443/). I did what I was supposed to do (installed pulseaudio-module-jack and pavucontrol) although I didn't find "~/.asound.conf" so I can configure it. And it didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I decided that I have to delete what I have just installed (pulseaudio-module-jack and pavucontrol) and Boom there you go. Google voice search is now working like there was no problem before :)

Comment: Installing and uninstalling did not work for me. I have added it to a bug report from 3 years ago. With me luck! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=check%20microphone&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=409406&thanks=409406&ts=1409421615