# I can not use the microphone on websites using chromium

Tags: snap, chromium, microphone, voice-recognition

I have a problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and chromium for some time. It also happens with Mint 19. In all applications or websites where I need to use the microphone (and that I could use before) such as dictation.io, or voice to text, when I press the microphone button to capture the sound, he always tells me "there is no Internet connection". I have Connection. Permissions to use the microphone too. And the microphone works well, because I can record with it.
I do not know what it can be, but any help will be appreciated, because I have searched and searched for the same problem and possible solutions and I have not found anything.
Thank you all for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install real Chrome instead of Chromium.

Comment: I've tried with Firefox and it says: " So Thanks!rry,  your browser does not support speech recognition :( 


 Please open dictation.io inside  Google Chrome  on your Windows PC or Mac OS to  continue using  Speech Recognition! "

Comment: Check out https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-settings/ubuntu/

Comment: Or maybe check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/801282/how-to-fix-check-your-microphone-in-chrome-for-16-04

Comment: I'va already done and eveything is working until I arrive to "Step 10: Open a terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and then run the gstreamer-properties". When I try it, gstreamer-ptoperties is not a command, and if I try to install it, it doesn't appears

Comment: Another thing you could try is real chrome not chromium Linux version at https://itsfoss.com/install-chrome-ubuntu/

Comment: The solution that says to uninstall pulseaudio-module-jack and pavucontrol can'0t work, because I have never installed

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio

Comment: I've installed all, but when I type in terminaql "$ gstreamer-properties
gstreamer-properties: orden no encontrada" (command not found)

Comment: Did you try real chrome like I suggested

Comment: Yes! Thank youvery much. I've installed the real chrome and it works fine!! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why did you downvote my anawe

Comment: I have upvoted!!! I'lll try to change it

Comment: When I try to vote up it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions of Ubuntu (19.10 and above, [ref.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190351/snap-packages-and-permissions)), Chromium is installed in a snap.  By default, snap isolation allows camera but not microphone.

You can change this graphically using  similar to [How do I give chromium permissions to read files of my /usr or /tmp folders? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144171/how-do-i-give-chromium-permissions-to-read-files-of-my-usr-or-tmp-folders) or via command line, ref. [How can Snap permissions be viewed and modified? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206951/how-can-snap-permissions-be-viewed-and-modified).

Command line access to graphical configuration:

```bsh
sudo gnome-software
```

Full command line solution:

```bsh
snap connections chromium  # to list existing permissions
sudo snap connect chromium:audio-record :audio-record  # to enable
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Ubuntu Software center and check Chromium permissions.

Currently it requires *"Record Audio"* and *"Play and record sound"* permissions for microphone in my *Ubuntu 20.04* system.

[image: chromium-permissions]

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine this was under "Ubuntu Software Center" was under "Settings".