# Snap packages and permissions

Tags: permissions, chromium, snap, 19.10

This is either a misunderstanding on my part and I am missing something obvious, or this will be only a rant.

Why is it that if packages are being moved to snap, that we now have to deal with permissions issues?  Example: Chromium.  I download anything, it gets put in a directory owned by root.  I then have to open a terminal and chown the files and move to them to the destination I wanted in the first place.  Am I missing an obvious solution to this problem?

If this is intended, since by design using snaps inherently isolates apps, and thus uses traditional users/groups, then this is a step backwards in the overall goal of usability of a linux desktop.

I am all for security, I work in IT Security.  But this is not an acceptable change to break functionality to the users.  It really is frustrating to me.

I am on 19.10, and if I understand correctly, Chromium will now only be released as snaps, no longer as debs.  Please tell me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Chromium devs have [announced their intent to go snap only](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/intent-to-provide-chromium-as-a-snap-only/5987/8) eighteen months ago, they're not there yet.  "[In most cases, Chromium is directly available in the official repository of each Linux distribution.](https://chromium.woolyss.com/#linux)"

You can still install the Chromium Browser without snap with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install chromium chromium-l10n` and you can still [download the binaries](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) to compile it yourself.

Why Snaps?

"Snaps, and the tool for using them, snapd, work across a range of Linux distributions (which use systemd), allowing distribution-agnostic upstream software packaging" per https://snapcraft.io/ .

Since the snap is a [compressed file containing all dependencies](https://hackernoon.com/managing-ubuntu-snaps-the-stuff-no-one-tells-you-625dfbe4b26c) , it's easier on developers as well as users. Since developers write neat stuff which make running Linux worthwhile, they like it.

Comment: Yeah, i wish it was as simple as that.  19.10 seems to be limited to snap only.  I know I can compile myself.  (grrrrr)  https://snapcraft.io/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition

Answer (score 0):

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-chromium-browser-deb-to-snap-transition/11179/22
lead me to 
https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement
and

````
lad ~$ snap info --verbose chromium
name:    chromium
summary: Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
health:
  status:  unknown
  message: health has not been set
publisher: Canonical✓
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   unset
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all
  Internet users to experience the web.
commands:
  - chromium.chromedriver
  - chromium
notes:               
  private:           false
  confinement:       strict
  devmode:           false
  jailmode:          false
  trymode:           false
  enabled:           true
  broken:            false
  ignore-validation: false
base:         core18
snap-id:      XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
tracking:     beta
refresh-date: 12 days ago, at 15:43 MST
channels:
  stable:    78.0.3904.97  2019-11-08 (937) 160MB -
  candidate: 78.0.3904.108 2019-11-19 (949) 160MB -
  beta:      79.0.3945.29  2019-11-08 (939) 155MB -
  edge:      80.0.3962.2   2019-11-11 (945) 155MB -
installed:   79.0.3945.29             (939) 155MB -
lad ~$ snap connections chromium
Interface                 Plug                               Slot                            Notes
audio-playback            chromium:audio-playback            :audio-playback                 -
audio-record              chromium:audio-record              -                               -
browser-support           chromium:browser-sandbox           :browser-support                -
camera                    chromium:camera                    :camera                         -
content[gtk-3-themes]     chromium:gtk-3-themes              gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes  -
content[icon-themes]      chromium:icon-themes               gtk-common-themes:icon-themes   -
content[sound-themes]     chromium:sound-themes              gtk-common-themes:sound-themes  -
cups-control              chromium:cups-control              :cups-control                   -
desktop                   chromium:desktop                   :desktop                        -
gsettings                 chromium:gsettings                 :gsettings                      -
home                      chromium:home                      :home                           -
mount-observe             chromium:mount-observe             -                               -
mpris                     -                                  chromium:mpris                  -
network                   chromium:network                   :network                        -
network-bind              chromium:network-bind              :network-bind                   -
network-manager           chromium:network-manager           -                               -
opengl                    chromium:opengl                    :opengl                         -
password-manager-service  chromium:password-manager-service  :password-manager-service       manual
personal-files            chromium:chromium-config           :personal-files                 -
pulseaudio                chromium:pulseaudio                :pulseaudio                     -
removable-media           chromium:removable-media           -                               -
screen-inhibit-control    chromium:screen-inhibit-control    :screen-inhibit-control         -
u2f-devices               chromium:u2f-devices               :u2f-devices                    -
unity7                    chromium:unity7                    :unity7                         -
upower-observe            chromium:upower-observe            :upower-observe                 -
x11                       chromium:x11                       :x11                            -
lad ~$ 

lad ~$ snap help refresh
<read this>
<in order to refresh, get an updated version or downgraded version>
lad ~$ sudo snap refresh --edge --classic chromium
<this did not work, you have to remove and re-add, losing settings and data>
lad ~$ sudo snap remove chromium
chromium removed
lad ~$ sudo snap install --edge --devmode chromium
lad ~$ snap info --verbose chromium
name:    chromium
summary: Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
health:
  status:  unknown
  message: health has not been set
publisher: Canonical✓
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   unset
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all
  Internet users to experience the web.
commands:
  - chromium.chromedriver
  - chromium
notes:               
  private:           false
  confinement:       strict
  devmode:           true
  jailmode:          false
  trymode:           false
  enabled:           true
  broken:            false
  ignore-validation: false
base:         core18
snap-id:      XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
tracking:     edge
refresh-date: today at 12:14 MST
channels:
  stable:    78.0.3904.97  2019-11-08 (937) 160MB -
  candidate: 78.0.3904.108 2019-11-19 (949) 160MB -
  beta:      79.0.3945.29  2019-11-08 (939) 155MB -
  edge:      80.0.3962.2   2019-11-11 (945) 155MB -
installed:   80.0.3962.2              (945) 155MB devmode
lad ~$ 
<breath fresh air again, no longer tied down>```
````