# Upload Files in Chromium which are stored in a Cloud-Storage

Tags: chromium, dropbox, google-drive

I use Chromium.

When I want to upload a file, then Chromium only let me choose local files which I have on my laptop.

I would like to upload images from a cloud-storage (gdrive, dropbox, onedrive, ...).

Is there a way to enable this?

BTW: I know that I can download the file from the cloud-storage, and then upload it from my local pc. But this is .... I am missing the right words. My goal is to reduce cognitive load.

Answer (score 1):

This restriction is due to Chromium being installed as a snap. snap applications run in a sandbox, a confined environment. To be able to reach your personal files in your home directory, you could enable the `home` interface. This obviously decreases the confinement of the browser, and hence security.

The snap of chrome is configured to [have a `home` interface](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190417/558158), so you can establish the connection with the command:

```
snap connect chromium:home :home
```

Your cloud storage must be mounted under your home directory for this to work. If it does not, then you may work around this by mount binding the directory where they are accessed to a directory under your home directory, as in

```
mount --bind /<path_to_network_drive> /home/<yourlogin>/<somefolder>
```

To make this permanent, you can add a line in  `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: No, I don't want to mount the cloud-storage to my PC. I just want to upload a file from the cloud-storage without download/upload or mount.

Comment: Mounting cloud storage to your drive is what you already do with the dropbox client and gdrive. If you rather want to do this without mount, then Chromium Snap will do that without any issue. This answer is just creating an extra path to the mount you already have, a path accessible by the snap.