# How can Snap permissions be viewed and modified?

Tags: permissions, snap, restricted-access

One of the promoted advantages of Snap packages is the sandboxing-feature, where a Snap program may not be able to access as much system information as a package from the repository.

Now, I have read a lot about permission problems with Snap software and how to fix them, but I don't know where to find actual information on what permissions a specific Snap package has.

The Snapcraft-website is also very brief about this.

As one concrete example: 
How can I find out what permissions the Discord Snap gets and (how) am I able to modify those permissions to basically only allow Pulseaudio/microphone access? (Because that's all it needs to have.)

Comment: Sorry in advance as I'm new to Ubuntu. Is this the documentation you're looking for- https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management . I don't currently have Ubuntu installed but last I remember I was also able to enable/disable snap permissions through the pre-installed Store app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [the link above](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management) to the documentation, I found this command to enable microphone access to the new chromium snap:

```sh
snap connections chromium  # to list existing permissions
sudo snap connect chromium:audio-record :audio-record  # to enable
```

The app must be restarted for new permissions to take effect.

(I'm not happy it took this long to find the answer, nor how obtuse the docs are.)

Comment: Don't forget to restart chromium browser after changing permission.