# VLC player is not working , Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: vlc

VLC media player is not working -  Ubuntu 23.04 , I just downloaded from Snap

error:

```
VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision 3.0.18-0-ge9eceaed4d)
[000055c2122faa00] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [0 205)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: A segmentation fault is the kind of error we can't solve here. It should be reported as a bug. [Here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_bugs/) is a how-to.

Comment: BTW All caps is both considered screaming and RUDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Snap permissions be viewed and modified?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206951/how-can-snap-permissions-be-viewed-and-modified)

Comment: Did you try to install VLC as a regular .deb package instead of snap?
I would recommend avoiding snaps whenever possible.

Comment: I get the same error. Ubuntu 23.04 changed to using virtual environments and moved away from system-wide installations of python/pip applications. This has broken a number of my applications that have python/pip dependencies, including all of my applications that have a dependency on qt. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/. I reinstalled using apt vlc as a short term workaround.

Answer (score 14):

Solution working for me:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```

Tested on:

```
snap    2.59.4
snapd   2.59.4
series  16
ubuntu  23.04
kernel  6.2.0-20-generic
```

Root cause: this issue https://github.com/keshavbhatt/olivia/issues/95#issuecomment-774747492

Comment: It might work, but it's the last thing I'll try on a brand new install. I think vlc is not supported.

Comment: this works for me

Comment: worked for me after an upgrade to ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 5):

I also used snap originally, try to avoid it when possible. What worked for me:

```
sudo snap remove vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: This answer goes against the official installation procedure and would require more solid arguments to stand

Comment: @Benjam - "It works" can be a solid argument. I tried other ways. This is just a media player. I am not supposed to be spending 30 minutes trying to understand what went wrong. I uninstalled using snap and reinstalled it. Nothing. Uninstalled and reinstalled using apt - Worked

Comment: thanks, works for me

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and my solution was installing edge version of vlc with this command:

```
sudo snap install vlc --edge
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem.
Thanks to [@karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel) this command solved the issue for me:

```
sudo snap connect vlc:network :network
```

Comment: Doesn't solve it for me. VLC stopped working after upgrading Ubuntu to 23.04.  Removing and reinstalling the snap doesn't help either.

Comment: I can't install it after 23.04.  sudo snap install vlc
error: cannot install "vlc": Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": dial tcp: lookup
       api.snapcraft.io on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving ... I think vlc is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Solution the worked for me was Resetting the font cache of vlc media player

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04
[Video: How to rebuild vlc font cache](https://youtu.be/miuIo_Q8VGA)