# Is there an equivalent snap command to the Flatpak's `permission-show` and `permission-set`?

Tags: permissions, firefox, snap, flatpak

I am asking, because I have to handle a permission problem with a Firefox webextension and the sandboxed Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04. (See https://github.com/mi-g/vdhcoapp/issues/139)

The solution turns out to be, I have to grant permission for Firefox to use that webextension. But I only find such commands in Flatpak's `permission-show` and `permission-set`, which means I have to install Flatpak to modify the permission of a *snap* application. That's weird.

Is there any permission managing scheme in *snap* itself? If not, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Snap permissions be viewed and modified?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206951/how-can-snap-permissions-be-viewed-and-modified)

Comment: @graham Thank you for the help, but no, this doesn't answer my question. I have posted an answer which links to a GitHub comment and that guy el-calvera have made an explanation to the necessity of using flatpak when dealing with the permissions about 'Native messaging'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the permission through `dbus`, the command bellow will set the permissions using the current user session and does not need flatpak installed. There are other methods in also, see [documentation](https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-impl-portal-PermissionStore.SetPermission).

```
dbus-send --print-reply \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore \
    /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore \
    org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.SetPermission \
    string:'webextensions' \
    boolean:'true' \
    string:'<your-extension>' \
    string:'snap.firefox' \
    array:string:'yes'
```

There is no way that I found to set the permissions for the system, this has to be done per session.

Answer (score 0):

Thank el-calavera in this link: https://github.com/mi-g/vdhcoapp/issues/139#issuecomment-1535179270 that answers my question.

I will just quote her/his answer here:

"Native messenging in snap is using the xdg-desktop-portal framework which grew out of the flatpak project. This is why permissions are stored in a file called ~/.local/share/flatpak/db/webextensions . Flatpak provides a way to edit this file, snap does not."

That means we have to use flatpak to manage these permissions regarding native messaging.